# Gvim can not load my Python

Tags: python, vim

I wanna use gvim (on windows 7) as my Python IDE, but gvim can not load my python.
My os is Windows 7 X64 with SP1, I use Python35 (64)

I run :version in gvim, the output includes:

....

```
+python/dyn

+python3/dyn
```

...

Compilation: ...

```
-DFEAT_PYTHON -DDYNMIC_PYTHON -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON_DLL=\"python27.dll\" -DFEAT_PYTHON3 -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON3 -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON3_DLL=\"python35.dll\"
```

....

It means this gvim compiled with python and python3 support ,
but when I run

```
:echo has("python")
```

or

```
:echo has("python3")
```

both return 0

the result of :python print(3)  is :

> E370: Could not load library python27.dll
>
> E263: Sorry,this command is disabled,the Python library could not be
>   loaded.

My python35 directory is C:\Python35 ,and it is in my PATH.

Why is this ?  Does gvim only search for python27 ,not python35 ?

I follow this [vim-ipython-failed-on-windows-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205281/vim-ipython-failed-on-windows-7) and try to edit my registry ,but it did not work.

Do I have to recompile gvim myself ,or should I give up gvim ?

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691408/install-gvim-on-windows-with-python3-support

Comment: @Ashish Nitin Patil  Thanks, but I think it is not my situation. The version of python and gvim required matched. It still does not work.

Comment: What's with the escaped quotes around `\"python27.dll\"', etc.? I'd expect them to become part of the filename it tries to look up. Do all the other DLLs in the listing have them?

Comment: Anyway it clearly tries to load the non-existent `python27.dll`. Maybe you need to tell it to load the PYTHON3 feature when it sees a `.py` file?

Comment: @alexis  The output of version command is too long, but all the .dll files have escaped quotes \"  . I did nothing,but when I type :py3 print('hello')  It works.

Comment: Then it's pretty clear: The `:py3` command is linked to `python35.dll`, but the `:python` command is linked to the non-existent `python27.dll` (as I'd suggested). Does this resolve the problem, or is there more?

Answer (score 6):

Your problem as someone else mentioned in passing is that you are using gvim--which is 32-bit only; there used to be 64-bit gvim build but was discontinued (vim.org says so). If you have "+python/dyn" and "+python3\dyn" (default as of 8.1 gvim binary from vim.org) then vim just needs to know where the 32-bit (not 64-bit like you said you have installed) version of python36.dll is (name it looks for it in gvim 8.1). If you can open up cmd.exe and run 'python' and you get a python 3 prompt then python36.dll is available on your path and gvim will know where to find it. I had the same issue, but uninstalling 64-bit version and reinstalling python 3.6.6 from python.org using x86 version, gvim picked it up and it worked. Try a quick `:py3 print('hello')` and if you get "hello" echo'd back, then everything is set up right.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, I solved the problem by installing the 32bit version of python as well.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem also. I reinstalled python several times, made sure that both python and Vim were the same architecture (both 32bit) with no success. The only thing that solved it was to copy python27.dll into Vim's directory. A bit crude but it works!

Comment: This is not a good suggestion. It's better to add the path to Python to PATH environment variable (because Python requires the other files in the directory too)

Answer (score 3):

The `:python` command will use the Python 2[.7] interpreter. As you only have installed Python 3[.5], you need to use the `:python3` / `:py3` command.